# Tic Tac Toe - with user intput in Java

Tags: java

So I have the following entries in the game:
Example 1:
Enter cells: XXXOO__O_
Example 2:
Enter cells: XOXOXOXXO
Example 3:
Enter cells: XOOOXOXXO
Example 4:
Enter cells: XOXOOXXXO
Example 5:
Enter cells: XO_OOX_X_
Example 6:
Enter cells: XO_XO_XOX

I am failing test 2 with the following code, and I am unable to termine what is wrong:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT7EH.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        System.out.println("X O X");
        System.out.println("O X O");
        System.out.println("X X O");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(0) + " " + input.charAt(1) + " " + input.charAt(2) + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(3) + " " + input.charAt(4) + " " + input.charAt(5) + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(6) + " " + input.charAt(7) + " " + input.charAt(8) + " |");
        System.out.println("--------");

        // convert into a 2D array
        int r = 3;
        int c = 3;
        int k = 0;
        char [][] array = new char[r][c];
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(k < input.length())
                    array[i][j] = input.charAt(k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        // printing the 2D array
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //resolution
        int x = 0;
        int sumX = 0;
        int sumO = 0;
        int diagX = 0;
        int diagXSecond = 0;
        int diagO = 0;
        int diagOSecond = 0;
        int columnX = 0;
        int columnO = 0;
            //rows
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    if ((int)array[i][j] == 79) {
                        sumO = sumO + (int)array[i][j];
                        if (sumO >= 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][j] == 88) {
                        sumX = sumX + array[i][j];
                        if (sumX >= 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // primary diagonal
                    if ((i == j) && (int)array[i][j] == 88){
                        diagX = diagX + (int)array[i][j];
                        if (diagX == 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((i == j) && (int)array[i][j] == 79) {
                        diagO = diagO + (int)array[i][j];
                        if (diagO == 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // secondary diagonal
                    if ((i + j) == (r - 1) && ((int)array[i][j] == 88)){
                        diagXSecond = diagXSecond + (int)array[i][j];
                        if (diagXSecond == 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((i + j) == (r - 1) && ((int)array[i][j] == 79)){
                        diagOSecond = diagOSecond + (int)array[i][j];
                        if (diagOSecond == 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // column logic
                    if ((int)array[i][0] == 79) {
                        columnO = columnO + (int)array[0][i];
                        if (columnO == 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][1] == 79) {
                        columnO = columnO + (int)array[1][i];
                        if (columnO == 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][2] == 79) {
                        columnO = columnO + (int)array[2][i];
                        if (columnO == 237) {
                            System.out.println("O wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][0] == 88) {
                        columnX = columnX + (int)array[0][i];
                        if (columnX == 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][1] == 88) {
                        columnX = columnX + (int)array[1][i];
                        if (columnX == 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ((int)array[i][2] == 88) {
                        columnX = columnX + (int)array[2][i];
                        if (columnX == 264) {
                            System.out.println("X wins");
                            break;
                            }
                    }

          }
            sumO = 0;
            sumX = 0;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, the test cases are not self explanatory. Kindly explain in form of a 2d array or images of the graph/tic-tac-toe table with the test cases marked on it.

Comment: `sumO >= 237` should be `sumO==237` instead: a line that looks like OOX will be summed up as 'O'+'O'+'X' == 255, which is greater than 237 and would score as a win for O.  All in all, though, wouldn't it make more sense to just **count** the Xs or Os instead and declare a win when you count 3 of the same?

Answer (score 0):

so based on your feedback I managed to solve the issue, thanks guys :)

```
package tictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    // global variables
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String input = scanner.nextLine();
    static int r = 3;
    static int c = 3;
    static char [][] array = new char[r][c];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        System.out.println("X O X");
        System.out.println("O X O");
        System.out.println("X X O");

        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(0) + " " + input.charAt(1) + " " + input.charAt(2) + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(3) + " " + input.charAt(4) + " " + input.charAt(5) + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + input.charAt(6) + " " + input.charAt(7) + " " + input.charAt(8) + " |");
        System.out.println("--------");

        // convert into a 2D array
        array = arrayTransformation(input);

        // printing the 2D array
        printArray(array);

        //invoke who wins
        System.out.println(whoWins(array));

    }

    // transforming the String into a 2D array
    public static char [][] arrayTransformation(String input) {
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                if(k < input.length())
                    array[i][j] = input.charAt(k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    // printing the 2D array
    public static void printArray(char[][] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //determine who wins logic
    public static String whoWins(char[][] array) {
        //counter values
        int rowCtX = 0;
        int rowCtO = 0;
        int diagX = 0;
        int diagXSecond = 0;
        int diagO = 0;
        int diagOSecond = 0;
        int columnX = 0;
        int columnO = 0;
        String winner = "Draw";

        int innerCtX = 0;
        int innerCtO = 0;

        //booleans for impossible states
        boolean rowX = false;
        boolean rowO = false;
        boolean colX = false;
        boolean colO = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
                //row checking logic
                if (array[i][j] == 'X') {
                    innerCtX++;
                    rowCtX++;
                    if (rowCtX == 3) {
                        rowX = true;
                        winner = "X wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if (array[i][j] == 'O') {
                    innerCtO++;
                    rowCtO++;
                    if (rowCtO == 3) {
                        rowO = true;
                        winner = "O wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if ((i == j) && array[i][j] == 'X'){
                    diagX++ ;
                    if (diagX == 3) {
                        winner = "X wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if ((i == j) && array[i][j] == 'O') {
                    diagO++;
                    if (diagO == 3) {
                        winner = "O wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if ((i + j) == (r - 1) && (array[i][j] == 'X')){
                    diagXSecond++;
                    if (diagXSecond == 3) {
                        winner = "X wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if ((i + j) == (r - 1) && (array[i][j] == 'O')){
                    diagOSecond++;
                    if (diagOSecond == 3) {
                        winner = "X wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                // column logic
                if (array[j][i] == 'X') {
                    columnX++;
                    if (columnX == 3) {
                        colX = true;
                        winner = "X wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                if (array[j][i] == 'O') {
                    columnO++;
                    if (columnO == 3) {
                        colO = true;
                        winner = "O wins";
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                // draw logic
                if ((array[i][j] == '_' || array[i][j] == ' ') && winner.equals("Draw")) {
                    winner = "Game not finished";
                    //break;
                }

                //impossible states
                if (colX && colO)  {
                    winner = "Impossible";
                } else if (rowX && rowO) {
                    winner = "Impossible";
                }

            }

            rowCtX = 0;
            rowCtO = 0;
            columnX = 0;
            columnO = 0;
        }
        int diffX = innerCtX - innerCtO;
        int diffO = innerCtO - innerCtX;
        if ((diffX >= 2) || (diffO >= 2)) {
            winner = "Impossible";
        }

        return winner;
    }



}
```